# An error of variable scope experiment.hs:150:23: error

Tags: haskell

I am trying to use the following function, from http://learnyouahaskell.com/modules:

```
numUniques :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Int
numUniques = length . nub
```

I have typed the above code onto an emacs file. On GHCi I have imported the `Data.List` module with `import Data.List`.
However, when I upload the file onto GHCi, I receive

```
experiment.hs:150:23: error:
Variable not in scope: nub :: [a] -> t0 a0
|
150 | numUniques = length . nub     |                       ^^^
```

There are various questions here about the message `Variable not in scope`. However, it is not clear to me how they are able to help me with the problem I am having. From other answers I have gathered that "Not in scope" means you are trying to use a name which is not defined in the place in which you are trying to use it.

However, I do not know which name this is.

I have tried putting the following code into my emacs file, and then loading GHCi with it:

```
import Data.List  

numUniques :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Int
numUniques = length . nub
```

However, I receive the following message:

```
experiment.hs:149:1: error: parse error on input ‘import’
|
 149 | import Data.List       | ^^^^^^
```

Comment: As a general tip, when a parse error arises, it is often due to what is before that point -- especially is that line looks OK.

Answer (score 1):

The name in question is the one that's after the colon, i.e. `nub`.

`nub` is defined inside the `Data.List` module. You've said that you've imported that module in GHCi, but that does not matter because you're not using `nub` in GHCi, you're using `nub` in your Haskell file, which presumably did not import `Data.List`.

Imports only apply to the file containing the import statement. If you import something in GHCi that only affects the code you enter into GHCi, it does not affect code you load from a file. In other words: you should write the import into your `experiment.hs`, not GHCi.

Comment: Thanks. I tried importing `Data.List` into my emacs file, and I received                                                                
              `experiment.hs:149:1: error: parse error on input ‘import’
    |
149 | import Data.List       | ^^^^^^`

Comment: @user65526 Where did you put the import? It should be at the beginning of the module (right after the `module Name where` line or at the beginning of the file if there is no module line).

Comment: It wasn't at the beginning of the file. Problem solved. :)